# Adding script maps during installation of web application IIS

Tags: iis, wix

has anyone successfully added IIS script maps to their Wix installation. I have been using this:

```
  <CustomAction Id="AddHandlers_Cmd" Property="AddHandlers" Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd&quot; set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /+&quot;[\[]name='GSOAP',path='*.dll', verb='*',modules='IsapiModule',scriptProcessor='[BIN]mod_gsoap.dll',resourceType='File', requireAccess='Execute'[\]]&quot;" Execute="immediate"/>
  <CustomAction Id="AddHandlers" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>
```

However I get the 404 errors from my web application and when I add the script map manually after installing the application it works perfectly. I would appreciate if anyone could share how they done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with GSOAP handler, but used ASP.NET ISAPI extention. I suppose basically it has the same level of integration. I will post the code for ASP.NET and I hope you won't have problem with changing it to GSOAP. I have a huge risk of changing something incorrectly and make the examples unusable for you, so I let you do it better.

Here is my code to register extention itself if it isn't

```
<Component Id="Iis6ConfigExtentions" Guid="{GuidHash({ProductId}-1822E4F3-5850-47D5-9281-D1E0E20C77D4)}" KeyPath="yes" Permanent="yes">
    <Condition><![CDATA[Installed OR (IISMAJORVERSION AND (IISMAJORVERSION = "#6"))]]></Condition>
    <iis:WebServiceExtension Id="ExtensionASP4" Group="ASP.NET v4.0.30319" Allow="yes" File="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" Description="ASP.NET v4.0.30319"/>
</Component>
```

and for adding those to the concrete site you need to use WebApplicationExtention, as @Yan already mentioned:

```
<iis:WebApplication Id="IIS6WebApp" Name="[SITE_APP_NAME]" WebAppPool="AppPool" >
  <iis:WebApplicationExtension Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST" CheckPath="no" Script="yes" Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" />
</iis:WebApplication>
```

The `CheckPath="no"` is required on IIS 6 because we use ASP.NET MVC which doesn't map urls to files on disk. You might need it too since service address probably doesn't map to physical file.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like it is really not possible to do it directly in WIX (at least in 3.5 version). You are going in right direction - custom action using appcmd. But the provided custom actions aren't complete or what you need: the first one just sets property value to the command you need to execute and the second one calls some Dll custom action which wasn't provided.

What I'd try to execute is:

```
<CustomAction Id="AddGsoapHandler" Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" Return="check" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /+&quot;[\[]name='GSOAP',path='*.dll', verb='*',modules='IsapiModule',scriptProcessor='[BIN]mod_gsoap.dll',resourceType='File', requireAccess='Execute'[\]]&quot; /commit:apphost" />
```

Please pay attention to the **path** attribute of your handler configuration. **It will limit handler usage to only URL's which ends with ".dll"** - I just copied it from your code but not sure if you've done it intentionally or just copied from [example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753249%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) at Microsoft site. That might have led to 401 error even if handler is registered successfully.

Also I added the `/commit:apphost` argument. Not sure if you really need this, but I use it to explicitly specify that I need to configure my application's config.

**UPDATE 2:**

If you need to set configuration to only single application, you should specify application object as argument of appcmd instead of the 'config' which means global configuration. Please try this:

```
<CustomAction Id="AddGsoapHandler" Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" Return="check" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "MySite/app1" -section:system.webServer/handlers /+&quot;[\[]name='GSOAP',path='*.dll', verb='*',modules='IsapiModule',scriptProcessor='[BIN]mod_gsoap.dll',resourceType='File', requireAccess='Execute'[\]]&quot; /commit:apphost" />
```

For more details you can read [this tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe).

Comment: Its now getting added in the ISAPI and CGI restrictions but nothing in the handler mappings. Only back to work from sickness so will run a verbose log. Thanks

Comment: To be honest I didn't expect the bounty for such guess which wasn't correct at the end. That made me to investigate your problem deeper to justify the bounty. Please see update section. It's odd that even bounty doesn't help to get good answer for WIX question on time.

Comment: Thanks, I awarded the bounty as I had too within that given timeframe and as you had helped solve halve the problem I guessed I should award it for your efforts instead of not awarding it to anyone. Thanks for the update I will test it now..:)

Comment: I see it is now putting the GSOAP into the NATATALIEPC home but it is not present in the application handler mappings. Do you know if I am missing something?

Comment: Added one more update - specificly for application configuration. You definitely are having problems with appcmd now, not with WIX actually. Probably it will be easier to test those commands in command-line and find which do you need. I'm not very confident with appcmd and can't test the command you need - just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to add handler mapping to your web application. If that's the case, then you don't need a custom action to accomplish this.

Take a look at [WebApplicationExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_webapplicationextension.htm) element.

Comment: Thanks Yan, but when I use this it does not show in the Handler Mappings `<iis:WebApplicationExtension Extension='dll' CheckPath="no" Executable="[BIN]\mod_gsoap.dll" Verbs="*"/>`

Comment: Strange... What does the installation log say?

Answer (score 1):

We are writing a separate Custom action in C# and Schedule it in after install Finalize to add handlers.

Try this, you can do anything with your own custom action.

Comment: Scheduling anything after InstallFinalize is generally a bad idea - you can't roll it back in case of failure. If you need to change the system state somehow, you'd better schedule this custom action between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize, and author corresponding rollback custom action.